Issue with flex-grow and flex-direction: column; - flex parent has a defined height
I have been trying to build my portfolio from the ground up instead of using a WYSIWYG website builder thats gonna cost me a lot anyways. It's been going well thus far. Except for my current issue:
I wanted to display some images in a sleek way and decided to use Flexbox to do so, the markup works well on desktop width when using flex-direction: row;, however when using flex-direction: column; for mobile an issue occurs where flex-grow/flex seems to be ignored.


/* Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    .split-container {flex-direction: column;}
}
/* Medium devices */
@media only screen and (min-width: 810px) {
    .split-container {flex-direction: row;}
}
/* Desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .split-container {flex-direction: row;}
}

body {
  width: 100%;
 }
 
.container-xl {
  padding 30px 30px;
}

.case-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 30px;
}

.split-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    gap: 10px;
}

.split-container div {
    flex: 1;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.split-container div:hover {
    flex: 4;
}
.split-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-position: center center;
    object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="case-info">
            <div class="split-container">
                <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/1080"></div>
                <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/1080"></div>
                <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/1080"></div>
                <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/1080"></div>
                <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/1080"></div>
            </div>
            <h2>Example Header</h2>
            <h2>Example Paragaph</h2>
</div>



I have searching up similiar issues on Stackoverflow, and mostly the answer seems to revolve around giving the parent a fixed height, which I've already tried.
Thanks in advance.

Better make it runnable snippet, so we can test. When I run the code on fiddle I just see image, is that supposed to happen?

No it's not, let me just see if i can get it working.

It would be good to share some design to show what the result should be. Now, when I run the code it just shows an image .

I have just fixed it, i forgot to close the  when making my example for StackOverflow, also if it still only shows one image, try to expand your fiddle

@mrconcerned Sorry for not tagging you, I'm new to being a user on this platform.
I've got the snippet up and running now.

You are just missing min-height:0 and probably you want to switch the height 400px to width 400px

@SyndRain I want the width to fill, so width stays 100%. However I have tried both changing the width and giving it a min-height, and it changes nothing when the screen is less than 810px wide.
I want the images to react in flex-direction: column; like they do when they're in flex-direction: row;, as mentioned earlier i have looked at other Stackoverflow threads with similiar issues where the height is the problem, that just doesn't seem to be the case here.

Try to add min-height:0 and set flex-direction:column and you can see that the flex-grow transition works perfectly. jsFiddle

@SyndRain Adding min-height: 0; to the .split-container didn't seem to work but adding * { box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 0; min-height: 0; } to the CSS did, my week is saved, thank you.

@ferd It shouldn't be added to the split-container and definetly not *.  There's nothing to do with box-sizing as well. It should be added to the flex items, which are the children divs of the split-container. I would suggest checking the duplication link to understand how flex works and the jsFiddle example I've posted above.

@SyndRain I see, thank you, will do. Have a good day/evening wherever you are.
